# Grid Overlay Multiple Polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, vector-grid

I would like to create a grid of certain polygons on a map in order to designate survey areas. I have looked up some grid tutorials: however, they focus on creating a grid on top of the whole map, while I just want a grid only in the selected polygons.

Is there a way to only have a grid overlay an area defined by a polygon?

I am using ArcMap 10.3.1

Comment: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/data-reviewer/creating-a-polygon-grid-using-selected-features.htm

Answer (score 3):

I would do this using these two tools:

1. Select (Analysis) to select out the polygon(s) you want into a new feature class
2. Create Fishnet to create your "grid" using the feature class above to set its extent.